# Keep receiving Error - AttributeError: 'QuantumCircuit' object has no attribute 'save_statevector'

Tags: programming, qiskit, error-correction

I am attempting to code a feed-forward simulation of a QECC in Qiskit. Qiskit (to my knowledge) does not directly support feed-forward simulation, so I attempted a work-around. I call the simulator firstly:

```
    #c/q register
    self.qubits = QuantumRegister(9)
    self.round1 = ClassicalRegister(2)
    self.round2 = ClassicalRegister(3)
    self.decoded = ClassicalRegister(7)
    self.circuit = QuantumCircuit(self.qubits,self.round1,self.round2,self.decoded,name="circuit")

    #noise model
    self.noisy = NoiseModel()
    self.error_rate = self.error_rates
    self.error_two_qubit = errors.depolarizing_error(self.error_rate/15, 2)
    self.noisy.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(self.error_two_qubit, ['cx','cz','cy']

    #simulator backend
    self.simulator = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator',noise_model=self.noisy)
```

Next, I attempt to save the statevector after calling the first stabilizer operator:

```
    self.circuit.reset(self.qubits[7])
    self.circuit.reset(self.qubits[8])
    self.circuit.h(self.qubits[8])
    self.circuit.cx(self.qubits[8],self.qubits[7])
    self.circuit.cx(self.qubits[target1],self.qubits[7])
    self.circuit.cx(self.qubits[target2],self.qubits[8])
    self.circuit.cx(self.qubits[target3],self.qubits[7])
    self.circuit.cx(self.qubits[target4],self.qubits[8])
    self.circuit.cx(self.qubits[8],self.qubits[7])
    self.circuit.h(self.qubits[8])
    self.circuit.measure(self.qubits[7],self.round1[0])
    self.circuit.measure(self.qubits[8],self.round1[1])
    self.circuit.save_statevector()
```

I lastly then attempt to execute the code up to the save-point:

```
self.result = execute(self.circuit,self.simulator,shots=1).result()
self.statevector = self.result.get_statevector(self.circuit)
```

I am not entirely sure why the error I get is of the following form:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
self.circuit.save_statevector()
AttributeError: 'QuantumCircuit' object has no attribute 'save_statevector'
```

I have looked at the answers from the following URLs:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67362847/attributeerror-quantumcircuit-object-has-no-attribute-config
2. https://githubmemory.com/repo/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/6346?page=2 .

I still am not able to fix the issue. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What Qiskit version do you have?

Comment: qiskit==0.24.1
qiskit-aer==0.7.6
qiskit-aqua==0.8.2
qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.12.2
qiskit-ignis==0.5.2
qiskit-terra==0.16.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Qiskit's [release notes](https://qiskit.org/documentation/release_notes.html), it seems that `save_statevector` is added in version 0.25 (Aer 0.8.0)

So, upgrading Qiskit should fix this issue.

Comment: ah-ha! thanks. easy fix. Greatly appreciated!